# How to show only lines in line charts by using amcharts

Tags: php, amcharts, linechart

I make a line chart by using amcharts library. I want to show only line in my charts but it shows mountains type view. i search alot but could not find any solution.

Here is  the Screenshot of my chart:

[image]

AS you can see in image it shows like mountain i want to show only lines only.

And Here is the scipt of my chart:

```
<script>

          var chart8;

        var chartData8 = [

        <?php 

        $qry = "select DIVISION_NAME, sum(DISPATCH_QTY) DISPATCH_QTY,sum(TARGET_QTY) 
 TARGET_QTY,sum(DISPATCH_QTY)-sum(TARGET_QTY)  BALANCE_QTY from  (
 SELECT TO_CHAR(A.GP_MONTH_APP_FDATE,'MON-RR') DISPATCH_MONTH, A.DIVISION_ID, A.DIVISION_NAME , 
 A.GROUP_ID, NVL(B.TARGET_GROUP_NAME,'Others') GROUP_NAME, NVL(B.TARGET_QTY,0) TARGET_QTY, 
 A.DISPATCH_QTY,
NVL(B.TARGET_QTY,0) - NVL(A.DISPATCH_QTY,0) BALANCE_QTY,
ROUND( (NVL(b.TARGET_QTY,0)/1000000), 2) AS TARGET_QTY_MLN, ROUND( (NVL(A.DISPATCH_QTY,0)/1000000) 
,2) AS DISPATCH_QTY_MLN, ROUND( (NVL(NVL(B.TARGET_QTY,0) - NVL(A.DISPATCH_QTY,0),0)/1000000), 2) 
BALANCE_QTY_MLN 
FROM(
SELECT A.GP_MONTH_APP_FDATE, A.MARKET_SRNO DIVISION_ID, A.ZONE DIVISION_NAME, A.GROUP_ID, 
SUM(A.QUANTITY_OUT2) DISPATCH_QTY 
            FROM GATEPASS.V_DISPATCH_TRX A, GATEPASS.GP_TRN_MST B
            WHERE 1=1
            AND A.GP_SUB_TYPE = 1
            AND A.MST_STATUS  = 'O'
            AND A.REQUEST_TYPE = 'OGP'
            AND A.GP_NO = B.GDR (+)                
            AND TO_CHAR(A.APPROVED_DATE,'MON-RRRR') = '$fdate'
            and ( A.MARKET_SRNO = $division OR $division = 0 )             
            GROUP BY A.MARKET_SRNO, A.ZONE, A.GP_MONTH_APP_FDATE, A.GROUP_ID  
  ) A, ( SELECT A.DIVISION_ID TARGET_DIVISION_ID, A.DIVISION TARGET_DIVISION_NAME, A.GROUP_ID 
 TARGET_GROUP_ID, B.GROUP_NAME TARGET_GROUP_NAME, B.ORDER_ID, A.TRN_DATE TARGET_MONTH, 
 A.ALOCATED_QTY TARGET_QTY
   FROM PROD.MONTH_WISE_DIVISION_TARGET A, GATEPASS.DISPATCH_GROUP B WHERE A.GROUP_ID = B.GROUP_ID ) 
B
 WHERE A.GP_MONTH_APP_FDATE = B.TARGET_MONTH (+)
 AND A.DIVISION_ID = B.TARGET_DIVISION_ID (+)
 AND A.GROUP_ID  = B.TARGET_GROUP_ID (+) 
 ORDER BY A.DIVISION_NAME, B.TARGET_GROUP_NAME) where DIVISION_NAME not in('RND')
 group by DIVISION_NAME";
 $result = $db->select($qry);



        ?>

<?php foreach ($result as $val) { 
   ?>
            {


                "Division": '<?php echo $val['DIVISION_NAME'] ?>',
                 "Target": '<?php echo number_format($val['TARGET_QTY']/1000000,2) ?>',
                 "Actual": '<?php echo number_format($val['DISPATCH_QTY']/1000000, 2) ?>',
                 "Difference": '<?php echo number_format($val['BALANCE_QTY']/1000000, 2) ?>'                    

    },
<?php } ?>

        ];


        AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIAL CHART
            chart8 = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart8.dataProvider = chartData8;
            chart8.categoryField = "Division";
            chart8.startDuration = 1;
            chart8.depth3D = 50;
             chart8.angle = 45;
            chart8.marginRight = 80;
    chart8.plotAreaBorderColor = "#DADADA";
           // chart3.plotAreaBorderColor = "#DADADA";
            chart8.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 0;
    //chart8.responsive.enabled = true;
            // this single line makes the chart a bar chart
            //chart3.rotate = true;

            AmCharts.addInitHandler( function ( chart ) {
            // set base values
            var categoryWidth = 50;

            // calculate bottom margin based on number of data points
            var chartHeight = categoryWidth * chart.dataProvider.length;

            // set the value
            chart.div.style.height = chartHeight + 'px';

            }, ['serial'] );
            // AXES
            // Category
            var categoryAxis = chart8.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
            categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.color =  'red';

            // Value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.5;
            tickLength: 0;
    // valueAxis.minimum = 0;
    // valueAxis.maximum = 3.5;
            valueAxis.position = "bottom";
    valueAxis.color =  '';
            chart8.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPHS

            // second graph
            var graph9 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph9.type = "<?php echo $chart_type ?>";
            graph9.title = "Target";
            graph9.valueField = "Target";
            graph9.balloonText = "Target:[[value]]";
            graph9.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph9.fillColors = ["#FFD244"];
            graph9.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph9.labelText =  '[[value]]';
    graph9.labelRotation = 360;
    graph9.labelPosition = 'top-bottom'; // change to inside
    graph9.color =  '#000';
    graph9.labelColorField =  '#FFFFFF';
            chart8.addGraph(graph9);
           // first graph

            var graph8 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph8.type = "<?php echo $chart_type ?>";
            graph8.title = "Actual";
            graph8.valueField = "Actual";
            graph8.balloonText = "Actual:[[value]]";
            graph8.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph8.fillColors = ["#ee8989"]; 
            graph8.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph8.labelText =  '[[value]]';
    graph8.labelRotation = 360;
    graph8.labelPosition = 'top-bottom'; // change to inside
    graph8.marginRight = 10;
    graph8.color =  '#000';
    graph8.labelColorField =  '#FFFFFF';
            chart8.addGraph(graph8);

    if (graph8.type == 'column' && graph8.type == 'line') {
     var graph10 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph10.type = "<?php echo $chart_type ?>";
            graph10.title = "Difference";
            graph10.valueField = "Difference";
            graph10.balloonText = "Difference:[[value]]";
            graph10.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph10.fillColors = ["#6acb5f"]; 
            graph10.labelText =  '[[value]]';
            graph10.labelRotation = 360;
            graph10.labelPosition = 'top-bottom';
            graph10.marginRight = 10;
            graph10.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph10.color =  '#000';
            graph10.labelColorField =  '#FFFFFF';
            chart8.addGraph(graph10);
          }

            // LEGEND
           //  var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
           // chart8.addLegend(legend);
           // legend.

           // console.log(legend);


           var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                            legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                            legend.position = "bottom";
                            legend.align = "center";
                            legend.markerType = "circle";
                            // legend.labelText = '[[title]]';
            chart8.addLegend(legend);

            chart8.creditsPosition = "top-right";
            // WRITE
            chart8.write("dailyprod");
        });
  </script>
```

Please hep me to get rid of this issue. Thanks

Comment: hi remove the depth3D ,fillColors  then try

Comment: Hi nothing would be happen to remove depth3d, fillcolors @SalunkeAkash

Comment: i want 3d effect thats why i use depth3d

Comment: You can try with `fillAlphas = 0;` or replace the fill with stroke.